# Error in compiling a Markdown file that doesn't have previous errors, but I can't knit

Tags: r-markdown

I have an .Rmd file with no errors in it, but when I compile it by knitting, it appears an error like this:

> C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
> midterm_18_19---practicat-a-casa-amb-les-correcions.utf8.md --to latex
> --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output midterm_18_19---practicat-a-casa-amb-les-correcions.tex
> --self-contained --number-sections --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in"  output file:
> midterm_18_19---practicat-a-casa-amb-les-correcions.knit.md
>
> pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xe9':
> Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1 Además: Warning
> messages: 1: In readLines(con, warn = FALSE) :   entrada inválida
> encontrada en la conexión de entrada
> 'midterm_18_19---practicat-a-casa-amb-les-correcions.Rmd' 2: In
> has_crop_tools() :  Tool(s) not installed or not in PATH: ghostcript
> -> As a result, figure cropping will be disabled. 3: In xfun::read_utf8(input) :   The file
> midterm_18_19---practicat-a-casa-amb-les-correcions.Rmd is not encoded
> in UTF-8. These lines contain invalid UTF-8 characters: 21, 23, 28,
> 38, 44, 49, ... 4: In readLines(con, warn = FALSE) :   entrada
> inválida encontrada en la conexión de entrada
> 'midterm_18_19---practicat-a-casa-amb-les-correcions.knit.md'
> Ejecución interrumpida'

Do you know what is that error for?

````
---
title: "Midterm Exam"
author: "Laia Casanellas"
date: 2019
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
  html_document:
   toc: no
fontsize: 12pt
fontfamily: mathpazo
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
acc <- acc %>% 
  mutate(
    causa_accident = recode(
      Descripció.causa.vianant,
      "Desobeir altres senyals" = "Altres"
      )
    )
```
````

My R version is the newest one (4.0.4.) and I've just updated my Latex version to the newest on (2020). Maybe it is a problem regarding the installation of the Latest, I don't know if I did it right.

Comment: So, you are trying to produce a PDF file from Rmd via LaTeX, aren't you? Would you edit your post and add [a minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I want to see the YAML section of your file to know the knitting configuration, though I suspect that \xe9 would be a non-ascii character on the body section, such as a character with an accent or tilde.

Comment: Hi Carlos! Thank you for your answer! I am not sure what you are asking me to do, but I edited the comment and add all the information I got in the console. This works? Thank you!

Comment: Um... You have just added the error message. It's also important but you should also put a short version of your Rmd file. If you add the [YAML section](https://ourcodingclub.github.io/tutorials/rmarkdown/#identify) which is marked by `---` (three dashes) and the short version of your content, it's pretty useful.

Comment: Okey! Thanks! This is the YAML section: ---
title: "Midterm Exam"
author: "Laia Casanellas"
date: 2019
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
  html_document:
    toc: no
fontsize: 12pt
fontfamily: mathpazo
---

Comment: And the content of my Rmd file is some basic operations relating the packets of Tidyverse and ggplot2 (basically, I made restructuring of databases and some plots). Thank you very much!

Comment: OK, now edit your original post, and add the YAML section and some tidyverse commands you use ***to the post***, not to the comment. That's the minimal working example. Don't forget the [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) of the example.

Comment: I think that's it, sorry for my naivety!

Comment: I fixed the code syntax highlighting in the MWE (please add the indent with four space characters to each line of the MWE next time).

Comment: I suspect some special characters such as the ones with accent, tilde, and cedilla in the database might hinder the process of LaTeX. To produce a PDF file dealing with such characters, you can change the latex engine like `latex_engine: xelatex`. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#latex-engine